# MySQL comma separated values into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rows

I'm trying to split string values, which is passed as the parameter to my SQL function into multiple rows. I tried many samples out there but I'm not able to find the correct output.

This is my code Here:

```
DROP function if exists F_Split;
DROP TABLE if exists temp1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1(val CHAR(255));
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION F_Split (x1 char(50)) 
RETURNS char(100)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE colval varchar(100);    
SET @sql = CONCAT("insert into temp1 (val) values ('", REPLACE(x1, ",", "'),('"),"');");
select val from temp1 into colval;
RETURN colval;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

select F_Split('6,4');
```

I'm calling F_Split('6,4') with a single parameter, I'm trying to store the values into a temp table and function needs to return 2 rows based on the comma separation. i.e

Excepted Output:

```
Row1:6
Row2:4
```

Actual Output:
Null.

I know the insert statement is not working properly but I'm not sure how to fix this. 
I want to Implement in the User Defined Function.
Help needed! Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want to install common_schema... see https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema then you can use `call tokenize('6.4', ',');` see http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/tokenize.html

Comment: tokenize is procedure but i need function. so that i can pass in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Return type of your user defined function is a char(100), not a table with 2 rows...

Anyway, function can't return table see here accepted return types https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html

Maybe you could create a stored procedure that populates a temporary table with splitted values but stored procedure can't be called in a select statement

Comment: No. I want to implement this using function only. because i need to call the function in the where clause

Comment: Oh. The function can't return table. Now how will I split these values using the function?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a query like this. The column id is only for testing. If you want split more values than 4 you must modify the UNION and also the CONCAT string ',,,,'

```
SELECT
    id
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ',', id), ',', -1) AS myvalue
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
) cnt
CROSS JOIN (SELECT CONCAT('123,456,6678',',,,,') AS val) AS c
HAVING myvalue <> '';
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     id
    ->     , SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ',', id), ',', -1) AS myvalue
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> ) cnt
    -> CROSS JOIN (SELECT CONCAT('123,456,6678',',,,,') AS val) AS c
    -> HAVING myvalue <> '';
+----+---------+
| id | myvalue |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 123     |
|  2 | 456     |
|  3 | 6678    |
+----+---------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```